# How to get a return value from a KendoUI modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

A have a KendoUI window that gets its content from a partial view.

That content can be, for example an input box.

What is the best way to get the value entered on that input box, when the window is closed?

I guess some kind of callback function must be used along the window's close event; if this is right, is it possible to post an example of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track. Here's an quickly drawn up sample that should help you get going:
[http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/DmAMc](http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/DmAMc/)

Comment: Love the inclusion of the custom animations.